# SP 2013 Migration to O365(sharepoint online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Team,

In SP 2013, We have application built with Infopath & SharePoint designer 2013 workflow.We have to migrate this to O365 using metalogix tool.

Approach:
 I have suggested to go with like to like migration instead of converting infopath to powerapps and workflow to designer. So after migrating the applications it remains same in O365. I have decided this because we have to restore the content with metadata.

Let me know your thoughts or any better solution/approach we can suggest here?

-Dhana

Answer (score 3):

Before making the choice I would do a proof of concept that the existing solution CAN be migrated 1:1.

Even if the migration is an option I would prefer to get rid of the technical dept and gain some hands on experience with Powerapps, you are going to need it soon anyway

Comment: But the timeline to deliver the apps is too short. This is the first application migrating to the customer. I am thinking to work parallel on gaining experience with powerapps

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Kasper about validating your assumption first.  In Q3 of 2018 I completed a migration of our entire farm to SharePoint Online/O365.  (Used the Metalogix migration tool)

Anyway, there were *almost* no issues with custom InfoPath applications and workflows coming over.

My strongest recommendation is that you **do not** perform what could be considered an *Upgrade* when what you are actually performing is a *Migration*.  I knew my users needed some time to digest the different environment, despite the similarities with on-prem.

Finally, what I did in my org was to stagger the different site collections for different roll out times.  e.g.: Week 1 was HR department, Week 2 was Marketing, etc.
As each site was migrated, I would create redirects in the on-prem SharePoint global.asax file so that any links pointing to the old site collection URL would redirect to SP Online tenant.